# C# : return dbnull.value or system.type from function?

Tags: c#, types, dbnull, system.type

I want to create a function (c#):

```
int PutInt (int? x)
{
    if (x.HasValue)
        return x.Value;
    else
        return DBNull.Value;
}
```

but there is no cast from int to DBNull.Value.
Is there any way to create such a function ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What does this have to do with the database?

Comment: i only wants to put int\dbnull to DB and build a functon with small algorithm that chooses what i need to put in DB )

Comment: Maybe you have a design problem. Why does a method called *PutInt* actually return an int?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets assume your DBMS is SQLServer, you can transform your function to

```
object PutInt (int? x)
{
    if (x.HasValue)
        return (object)x.Value;
    else
        return (object)DBNull.Value;
}
```

Because SQLParamater Value property assumes type object. Hope I answer your question.

Comment: What about `return x ?? (object)DBNull.Value;` ?

Answer (score 4):

This is inherently impossible—value types cannot be null.

You need to use a nullable type (`int?`), which makes your function utterly useless.

Comment: even if you use `int?`, I still don't think it will work as `DBNull` is not of `int?` type

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't cast `int` to `DBNull.Value`. This is used to evaluate the contents of database fields, not of nullable types. The value of a nullable type would simply be `null`.

A better option than the function that you've defined is to use the [**null coalescing operator**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) (`??`).

It has very similar logic to that which you've attempted to construct in your function. Consider the following lines of code:

```
// Declare a nullable int, and set it to null
int? x = null;

// Assign int y to x, unless x is null, in which case, set y = -1
int y = x ?? -1;

// The variable y now has a value of -1
Console.WriteLine(y);
```

Comment: Now that I look at the question again, I think you're spot on on what he wants.

Comment: @Bolt: Any theories on why it might have been downvoted, then? I haven't been doing so well recently with reading askers' minds. Costing me a lot of rep...

Comment: Bah. Looks like we both messed up then.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just assigning to object variable type, I suggest you just forget about using the method and just use conditional assignment

```
 object obj = (x.HasValue? x.Value : DBNull.Value);
```

Comment: This can be rewritten as `x ?? DBNull.Value`. Much prettier, huh?

Comment: No you can't, see my comment to SLaks below.

Comment: I just fired up VS and try it out and proof that you can't. If you tried using ??, you will get a compile error "Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'System.DBNull'"

Comment: Like this: `x ?? (object)DBNull.Value`

Comment: Your suggestion above still doesnt work. Give it a go in VS and see what you get. Also if you have to start explicitly boxing and etc. I presonally dont think it looks any prettier